# Configuring a framework using Selenium Builder, GitHub and Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, source-control

Ok, so I have posted a couple of other questions here that have been unclear so, apologies for another along similar lines.  I am a little further along now but am still blocked from progressing.  I think perhaps the community for Selenium Builder is not large at the moment and so I'm not finding the help out there.

My goal:
setup a simple test framework using Selenium Builder as a FF plugin, GitHub and Jenkins. Retain the test files in .json format. I don't wish to go near java or maven for now.

My current setup:
 - Selenium Builder add-on for FF28 with Github plugin
 - Jenkins 1.567 with SeleniumBuilder plugin 
 - Jenkins job setup as a freestyle project, building when a push is made to Git repo and 'Invoke selenium Builder script' as a build step with 'Script file' pointing to root of my test folder(.json scripts)

I can run my .json scripts using se-interpreter from command line using  java -jar SeInterpreter.jar example_test.json

What I need to know is - how do I configure Jenkins and the se-interpreter-config file so I can run from Jenkins? currently my interpeter config file looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "interpreter-config",
  "configurations": [
{
  "settings": [
    {
      "driverOptions": {
        "host": localhost,
        "port": 4444

      },
      "browserOptions": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
      }
    }
  ],
  "scripts": [

    "mySeleniumBuilderTests/tests/*"

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would [setup a Jenkins free-style job](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) and execute the [java based Se Interpreter](https://github.com/sebuilder/se-builder/wiki/Se-Interpreter) from a [shell-script](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands) task

1. Setup free-style Jenkins build
2. Schedule build with github with the [git-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to run job on each commit
3. Add a shell-script that runs the Se Interpeter in the build and make sure it has a correct exit code to fail/success the run or [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148122/how-to-mark-a-build-unstable-in-jenkins-when-running-shell-scripts) for options.

   Shell script would look something like this:

   > java -jar SeInterpreter.jar --driver=Remote --driver.browserName=firefox --driver.url=http://selenium_grid.local/wd/hub/ tests.json
4. Setup a [Selenium Grid hub and nodes](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) or use [the Jenkins SE Grid plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin) (which setups each Jenkins node as grid node, but you need to make sure the browsers can start on the Jenkins machines.) to run the tests against.

I would prefer a separate grid or even better run against [SauceLabs](https://saucelabs.com/) or [TestingBot](http://testingbot.com/), since [maintaining your own Grid could become cumbersome](http://www.vanreijmersdal.nl/577/creating-a-maintainable-selenium-2-grid-setup/) pretty soon.

There is also [a node.js version of the Se Interpreter](https://github.com/Zarkonnen/se-interpreter), which might be interesting for people running a JavaScript stack.

Comment: Niels - many thanks for the detailed reply.  As expected, I have some learning to do in respect of Selenium grid as I have not used before but what you've listed makes sense.